# Why is Scala not retaining field annotations here?

Tags: java, scala, annotations

I have this annotation that I have written in Java as Scala provides no way of defining annotations with runtime retention policy.

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface When {
    String event();
}
```

I have these two classes. One in Java.

```
public class TestJavaClass {
    @When(event = "something")
    public String someField;
}
```

Another in Scala.

```
case class TestScalaClass(@When(event = "something") someField: String)
```

The Java class, when reflected on, gives me the annotation as expected. Here is a Scala REPL session demonstrating that.

```
scala> classOf[TestJavaClass].getDeclaredField("someField").getAnnotations
res1: Array[java.lang.annotation.Annotation] = Array(@utils.When(event=something))
```

The Scala class, however, although it looks like it should be identical in this regard, doesn't.

```
scala> classOf[TestScalaClass].getDeclaredField("someField").getAnnotations
res2: Array[java.lang.annotation.Annotation] = Array()
```

Why is Scala losing the annotation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
case class TestScalaClass(@(When @annotation.meta.field)(event = "something") someField: String)
```

For artifacts, the meta annotation instructs it where to put the annotation.

The docs suggest an alias:

```
import annotation.meta._

object Helper {
  type Whenfield = When @field
}
import Helper._

case class TestScalaClass(@Whenfield(event = "something") someField: String)
```